# After completing download 100% from google play store app wont install. but after 3 to 4 hour it install itself. What could be the problem?

Tags: applications

After completing download 100% from google play store app wont install but after 3 to 4 hour it install itself. What could be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

can't say exactly but might be your device having low internal storage or your internet connection was interrupted or your device was busy with may background process

Comment: nop thats not the problem cua i have half GB free space and good net speed. But on the other hand i f i download apk from other sites then install them, then it installed without any problem.

Comment: i suffered for same problem with my Sony Xperia M . Definitely it's internal storage and Low RAM problem..kindly Root your device and Remove unused app and then use your device freely

Comment: may be the file you want to download was corrupted ..:)